# How can I change the colour of the toolbar in a FireMonkey mobile application

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe7, firemonkey-style

I'm using Delphi XE7 for developing mobile application. And how can I change the colour of the **TToolbar** component in Firemonkey mobile application? I can not find the option in the Object Inspector. Is there any other option to change the colour of this component. And I'm targeting Android platform.

Comment: I'm targeting for _Android_ and the component is  **TToolBar**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Method #1:** In Firemonkey most components can be contained within most other components. Place a TRectangle inside of your TToolBar component. Align it to Contents. Change the Fill color to the color you want. Change the Stroke.Kind property to None. Done.

**Method #2:** You can also do this by modifying the style. Drop the TToolBar on the form. Right click it and select Edit Custom Style.... You should see a toolbar1style1: TStyleObject in the Struction window. Find TRectangle in the Tool Palette. Drag and drop the TRectangle onto the toolbar1style1 line in the Structure window. It should add a TRectangle to your style. Set the Align to Contents. Set the Fill color to what you want. Set the Stroke.Kind to None. Apply and Close. Done.

It will create a custom TStyleBook on your form and your Toolbar should be the Fill color. This may be a less cluttered way than the first method. But could conflict with loading Premium styles into the TStyleBook. Therefor I think the first method is more forward compatible and more maintainable.

Comment: Note: Can't right-click -> edit style for Mobile applications via FMX

Comment: You can in Delphi XE7. I tested it again just now. In previous versions you can not.

Comment: Example source code: http://www.fmxexpress.com/toolbar-background-color-and-scrolling-marquee-demo-for-delphi-xe7-firemonkey-on-android-and-ios/

Answer (score 0):

[`TintColor`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.StdCtrls.TToolBar.TintColor) is the property that you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

If your target is the Android platform, I think you can use the [TintColor](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/FMX.StdCtrls.TToolBar.TintColor) property.
I have tested the behaviour in Delphi 10.1 Berlin, and it does work correctly.
Please note that the TintColor property is currently only available for mobile platforms (iOS and Android).